# Limit points of $ \alpha $ -normalized prime gaps

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory, prime-numbers

Let  $\mathbb{L}_{\alpha} $ be the set of limit points of  $ \{\dfrac{p_{n+1}-p_{n}}{\log^{\alpha}p_n}\}_{n=1..\infty} $. Erdös conjectured that  $\mathbb{L}_{1}=[0,\infty] $.
Has it been conjectured that  $ \lambda(\mathbb{L}_{1-x})\sim\lambda(\mathbb{L}_{1+x}) $ for all  $ x\in[0,1) $ where  $ \lambda $ is the Lebesgue measure? If yes do we know whether this quantity is a decreasing function of  $ x $ ?